# Git rollback/delete of pushed branch in PR

Tags: git

I have a local branch that has been pushed to a remote branch, but not yet merged to master, and a pr has been created for this change.  There are file(s) in this commit that don't belong.  I am wondering if the following will work:

- Save/shelve the files from local branch which I do want to push
- Delete the local branch and remote branch
- Create a new local branch from master, move back in the modified files that I want to commit, commit, and push to remote.
- Create a new pr

Thanks in advance for any help and assistance.

Comment: if it's a single revision on that branch, amend it then force-push on the same branch. That should be reflected on the pr.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I need to exclude it from being amended at all such that it is completely excluded from the changeset.  Also, I think I messed up my local branch by trying to revert it, so was hoping for a fresh start and wondered if the above steps would get me what I need.

Comment: @Mike Do you mean your actual workflow bans force pushing even on simple feature branches?

Comment: @RomainValeri gotta be honest git is all new to me so I don't even know to answer that question.  I'm just trying to figure out how to exclude a file that never should have been edited in the first place.  So in my head it seems that just editing the file to un-do the change still includes it in the push, and that is what I need not to happen.

Comment: @Mike Yeah that's what I suspected, no offense. And eftshift0's comment was (as usual) on point. I'll try to make an actual answer if he doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle is this : you don't actually need to delete this PR and create a new one. Modifying your local situation and pushing it onto the server will update the PR automatically. Steps below :

1) Amend your local branch (starting from your local branch checked out)

```
# undo the last commit whilst keeping the changes in the working tree (and staged files)
git reset --soft HEAD^

# remove the unwanted files from the to-be-committed list (the index)
git reset HEAD -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2
# as an alternative if you don't want to keep the changes in these files,
# use --hard here above, but before the --)

# redo the commit
git commit -m "your message here"
```

2) Push it to the remote with force (since the remote already has the old version of the commit but we got rid of it in our history)

```
git push --force origin HEAD
# or alternatively, since your branch is named br/bugfix1
git push --force origin br/bugfix1
```

3) Update the PR

Just go to your PR webpage and refresh it.

Comment: so far so good, I'm on the last step and want to verify that the "git push --force origin HEAD" is only pushing changes to my remote branch.  in other words, let's say my local/remote branch is named br/bugfix1.  so in the command line tool, that is what is indicated as the current branch.  So the command "git push --force origin HEAD" will push to the remote version of "br/bugfix1" correct?  and from above, no offense whatsoever, I'm glad and appreciative of the help.

Comment: @Mike I understand your cautiousness here, no offense taken :-) Yes, if your HEAD is still pointing on your local branch `br/bugfix1`, only it will be pushed, no other. You can also go for `git push origin br/bugfix1`

Comment: Cool, one last question and I promise (I hope) that's it....if I go for "git push origin br/bugfix1", I do not need --force?

Comment: @Mike Wow, my bad, but of course it doesn't change the need for `--force`, so finally : `git push --force origin br/bugfix1`. We'll never surrender to git! ...(thanks to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek), mostly ;-)